# SIGQUIT, Handling the Second signal with quick, successive calls

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to ignore the first `SIGQUIT` to a child thread...
Specifically, writing to console after each and exiting on the second call.

I have tried variants of this code; i.e. splitting into two functions per the similar stack overflow thread. Unfortunately it appears that the parent loop is 'too quick' for the child's handler.

Handler for `SIGQUIT`:

```
int goes = 0;

void install_handler(){ 

    write(1, "SIGQUIT\n", 8);

    if (goes == 1) exit(0); 

        goes += 1;
}
```

Just the driver:

```
{
    if((child_pid = fork()) < 0) exit(1);

    if (child_pid == 0 ) { 

        signal(SIGQUIT, install_handler);

        while(1){}

    } else { 

        sleep(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

        write(1, "KILLING\n", 8);

        kill(child_pid, SIGQUIT);

      //  sleep(1);


        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be ~

```
KILLING
SIGQUIT
KILLING
SIGQUIT
KILLING
...
```

The output (without a sleep in the parent loop) is

```
KILLING
KILLING
KILLING
SIGQUIT
SIGQUIT
```

Which is not the order I am trying to achieve. What is an effective way to ensure that on each signal of sigquit we can guarantee that "SIGQUIT" is written to console without modifying the `main()` method?

Comment: this looks like an XY problem. why do you need the output to be interleaved like that? signals are asynchronous, the fact that the `kill()` call returned doesn't mean that the signal was handled - it's subject to scheduling.

Comment: 100% need the interleaving like this! The output is string matched!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fun answer to your question.
but first as annoying as it is i am not allowed to comment so i hope i am not making any mistakes.

```
int goes = 0;
int child_pid = 0;

void install_handler(){ 
if (child_pid == 0) exit(0); //to exit the program once done
write(1, "SIGQUIT\n", 8);
kill(child_pid, SIGQUIT);
write(1, "KILLING\n", 8);
//you can put it after the if depending on the output
if (goes == 1)  {
kill(0, SIGQUIT);
exit(0);
} //this way the program will end himself at the end
// i guess the fact that goes was indented is a mistake
goes += 1;
}
```

as you can see i put the kill in the handler, this way kill won't be sent until another kill is received.
(notice how i called pid here?)

```
{
    if((child_pid = fork()) < 0) exit(1);

if (child_pid == 0 ) { 



    while(1){
        signal(SIGQUIT, install_handler);
    }

} else { 

    sleep(1);
    kill(child_pid, SIGQUIT);
    write(1, "KILLING\n", 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    signal(SIGQUIT, install_handler);
    wait(); //you might even not need the wait!


  //  sleep(1);


    }
}
return 0;
```

}

I strongly suggest using sigaction instead of signal, it is a lot more precise.
i must say i am not sure of my answer since i don't have c on this computer but usually i use sigaction and wait (instead of sleep)
also you don't need to to call it child_pid since it is and isn't the child pid, as it is two process

soooo... i hope i was usefull!